# Scrollable Dropdown Multiselect

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

Hey all I was wondering if there was a way for the multiselects that are selected to instead of moving the dropdown box down as it is populated, to have it stay the same size and a scroll appear.  Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery Chosen Multi Select:

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/